# AndroidStudio show usage of RAM

Tags: android-studio, ram

I have seen on other AndroidStudio-pictures, that there is a RAM usage at the right bottom. I tried to setup this statuslist o the bottom. But a rightclick didn`t help me. How can I switch on the RAM usage in AndroidStudio ?

Answer (score 45):

Android Studio above 4.0 - Bottom Bar > Right click > Enable Memory Indicator
[image: Update Answer]

Below 4.0 Setting > Appearance and enable Show memory indicator [image: Show memory indicator]

Comment: This answer is outdated

Comment: Right-clicking on the bottom IDE bar works for Android Studio Giraffe ✅ The option is labeled "Memory Indicator".

For some strange reason, it doesn't show up in the IDE settings anymore ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 25):

I am using 4.1.1. And also for latest version u can use following steps till now.

Bottom bar-> right click -> check Memory Indicator

[image]

Answer (score 10):

For me, this didn't work

> Setting > Appearance and enable Show memory indicator

For Android Studio 4.0 or higher, The way to show memory used by android studio in the IDE itself is View -> Appearance -> Status bar widgets ->  Memory Indidcator

Comment: Your welcome @twlkyao. glad I can help you.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe I misunderstood the question but I need to see the usage of ram in my application.

I found the solution here:

https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler

> Click View > Tool Windows > Profiler (you can also click Profile  in the toolbar).
>
> Select the device and app process you want to profile from the Android Profiler toolbar. If you've connected a device over USB but don't see it listed, ensure that you have enabled USB debugging.
> Click anywhere in the MEMORY timeline to open the Memory Profiler.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

go to Setting > Appearance & Behavior > Appearance > In Window Option Segment > tick "Show memory indicator" and save setting.

After that you can view memory indicator in bottom right corner, you can trigger garbage collector by click on memory bar.

Answer (score 0):

at the top of Android studio you'll find "Tools" (next to "Run" and "VCS"). Click it and go to "Android" --> "Android Device Monitor". A new Tab called "Android Monitor" is now added to your tooblar at the bottom. Click on it and you'll see stats like "Network" and "Memory".
I hope this solves your problem!

Cheers!