# Show memory indicator on Android Studio 4.1 Beta is missing

Tags: android, android-studio, beta

I am using Android Studio Beta 4.1, and I realised the "Show Memory Indicator" [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34566061/androidstudio-show-usage-of-ram) checkbox is missing in Preferences -> Appearance & Behaviour -> Windows Options

Any idea why?

[image]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It’s on the bottom bar. Right click on the bottom most bar and check "Memory Indicator". It’s the last item and is unchecked by default.

[image]

Comment: After struggling with myself, I came here.